# Building chart using charjs in Django

Tags: django, chart.js

I need to create a chart with chartjs with displaying month wise count on current year in a line chart. The data should be retrieved from the model named "invoice" and the feild name is "Invoice_date".

Note: Invoice_date is an DateFeild().

```
in views.py

def home(request):
    if request.user.is_authenticated:
        customers = User.objects.filter(groups__name='Customer').count()
        totalinvoice = invoice.objects.all().count()
        supplier = User.objects.filter(is_staff=True).count()

        # chart
        labels = ["Jan","Feb","Mar","Apr","Jun","Jul","Aug","Sep","Oct","Nov","Dec"]
        data = [12,14,19,25,28,80,23,35,46,78,45,23] // This data's should be retrieved dynamically

        return render(request, 'home.html', {
            'totalinvoices':totalinvoice,
            'customers':customers,
            'supplier':supplier,
            "labels":json.dumps(labels),
            "data":json.dumps(data),
        })
    else:
        return redirect("login")
```

Please someone help me in figuring out.

Answer (score 0):

try

```
data = invoice.objects.filter(invoice_date__year=2022).values('invoice_date__month').annotate(month_wise_count=Count('id')).order_by('invoice_date__month')
```

Then, while looping the data, do `datum['month_wise_count']`, or in template `{{ datum.month_wise_count }}`.

Please note that in practice, you should NOT use `.filter(invoice_date__year=2022)`. Replace 2022 with a variable denoting current year.

---

UPDATE: Example models I use to test the queryset.

```
# models.py 
class invoice(models.Model):
    invoice_date = models.DateField()
```

Testing

```
# python3 manage.py shell

# Step 1: create some random invoices
from django.utils import timezone
from .models import invoice
import random

random.seed(0) # be reproducible

date_0 = timezone.localdate().replace(2022, 1, 1)
a_day = timezone.timedelta(days=1)


for i in range(1000):
    rand_date = date_0 + random.randint(0, 364) * a_day
    invoice(invoice_date=rand_date).save()

# Step 2. Run the queryset. 
data = invoice.objects\
    .values('invoice_date__month')\
    .annotate(month_wise_count=Count('id'))\
    .order_by('invoice_date__month')

for datum in data:
    print(f"{datum['invoice_date__month']:2}. {datum['month_wise_count']}")
```

This generates following result:

```
 1: 84
 2: 89
 3: 92
 4: 78
 5: 74
 6: 79
 7: 84
 8: 92
 9: 79
10: 70
11: 90
12: 89
```

---

Apologize: I made a mistake to put `.order_by` before `.values`. It should be at the end of queryset. It is now correct.

Comment: I am facing this error.
```
TypeError at /
a number is required
```
In template i have kept
```
{{ datum.month_wise_count }} to loop.
```

Comment: I tried to build a simple model and tested the query set. It worked out well, at least in python shell. I will update my answer with it, and see if it helps you

Comment: Post your template and your new views.py, so that I can check how this error occurs